# Iphone - The executable was signed with invalid entitlements

Tags: iphone

I am trying to load an application on my iphone and this is the error I am receiving. Does anyone know how to fix this. I have searched the forums and S.O. and I cannot find the answer.

The entitlements specified in your application’s Code Signing Entitlements file do not match those specified in your provisioning profile.

Answer (score 0):

Well....after a few hours I figured out the problem. I included the Entitlements.plist into my build setting and it worked. Now my question is why did it work once I included this???

Comment: Isn't that the most upvoted answer to the question that Matthew linked you to?

Comment: I read that article last night trying to fix this problem..so my mind was a little cloudy and I wrote it off. Although when I tried it, it obviously didn't work or else I wouldn't have posted here. I apologize Matt